# Align ending quotes to left?

Tags: html, css, quotes

I've created this [**simple example**](http://jsbin.com/eheyok/2/edit) which yields this html :

[image]

But I have a problem trying to align the right closing `"` to the end of the text(*after the "posted" word*)

alert('');

How can I align it ? ( currently it has `float:left`)

*(please notice this question is not tagged as javascript.)*

Comment: How about http://jsbin.com/eheyok/8/edit

Comment: Why don't you use `blockquote p:after` instead?

Comment: Please include your code in the question body. I just found it in the close vote review, this is a good question I would hate to see it closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look:
http://jsbin.com/eheyok/20/edit

Here is the trick:

```
blockquote :last-child{
  display:inline;
}

blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  display: inline-block;
  top:20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you please _explain_ why you add the position:relative ? if it's "inline" then it should be flow like normal text like 2 sequential spans.

Comment: @RoyiNamir it is just for `top` property to take effect. Note that `blockquote :last-child` relates not to `:after` - pseudo element ,  but to "real" child , `p` in your case. Actually , this rule is what solves the issue.

Comment: @chrniv please open this(http://jsbin.com/eheyok/42/edit) at IE10 - why does the last line has a different height ?  how can i fix that ?

Comment: You're the man. but why does the `vertical align ` which relates to the `"` which is position relative -- has effect on the line height ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's relative , but it's still `inline-block` , which means that it can affect the line it sits in

Answer (score 1):

If you want

[image]

then the following

```
blockquote {
  line-height: 130%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px 1px 10px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  quotes: '\201C' '\201D';
}
blockquote p{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 14px 10px;
  margin:0;
}
blockquote p:before {
  content: open-quote;
}

blockquote p:after {
  content: close-quote;
  bottom:-0.25em;
}

blockquote p:before, blockquote p:after {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 4em;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  position:relative;
}
```

will suffice..

**Demo at** http://jsbin.com/eheyok/29/edit

Answer (score 0):

I edited the CSS to make the quote align with the text.
I don't recommend doing it like this, unless you know for sure that your text is going to be this length every time.

```
blockquote:after {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 170px;
content: close-quote;
font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/eheyok/9/edit

But just to expand on my answer:
the margin-right/margin-left styles above help set the margins on either side (aka how far over this particular item is going to start/end before it can no longer be on that line).
I added the position so that the quotes would jump to the line above it.
And then subtracted some of the length off to get it just right (the "top" property), since the size of the quote and the size of the text are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote,    pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;font-size: 14px;
 }


body 
{ 
background-color: White;
font-family: Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}
blockquote { quotes: '\201C' '\201D'; }


blockquote:before {
float:left;
font-family: 'Times New Roman';
content: open-quote;
}

blockquote:after {
content: close-quote;
font-family: 'Times New Roman';
float: right;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
font-weight: bold;
color: #cccccc;
font-size: 4em;
}


blockquote {line-height: 120%;
padding: 10px 0px 1px 10px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Source:

http://jsbin.com/eheyok/19/edit